# Create a numeric text box in java Swing with increment and decrement buttons

Tags: java, swing, textbox, numeric

How can I create a numeric text box in java swing , which has two buttons (up and down) which increments and decrements the value in the text box respectively. Also this text box must be editable with **ONLY NUMERIC VALUES**. Something like this

[image: Numeric Text Box]

I tried by placing two buttons near a text box and manually doing the operation on button click.

[image: My try Text Box]

Is there any other method in which I can do this in a better way and achieve a similar result as the first image.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use [JSpinner](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JSpinner.html)

[How to use Spinners in java](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html)

---

Based on your comment:

```
SpinnerModel model = new SpinnerNumberModel(9.9, 1, 15, 0.1);     
JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(model);
```

Comment: Can this be used to increment and decrement in steps of 0.1, cos, when I implemented the other way, float gave things like, `9.8000000000007` when decremented from `9.9` and similar problems

Comment: Use a [SpinnerNumberModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SpinnerNumberModel.html) for this. Provide 0.1 in step to make it change value by 0.1.

Answer (score 2):

[JSpinner](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) need for allows numeric input only, required some hack for that in its Model, but your 2nd. picture looks like as two [JButtons](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) (with JButton#setFocucPainted(false)), and one [JFormattedTextField](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) with number Format, with min/maxDecimalPaces, with roundingMode

```
myDoubleFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
myDoubleForma.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
myDoubleForma.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

then [Action](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) from `JButton` will be

```
myFtdTextField.setValue(((Number) myFtdTextField.getValue()).doubleValue() +/- 0.1)
```

Comment: actually I need to create something similar to the first image, as i dont know how, I manually did it using two buttons and a text box. But think JSpinner did the trick.. :) Thanks :)

Comment: @Balanivash you are welcome :-) alternative always exist, about my post, nobody knows..., but for JSinner you have to implents this hack, read carrefully http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=9337792&#9337792